# Not receiving an Intent back from Zxing barcode scanner

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I know some others have had this problem but I've followed the solutions and it still isn't working for me.

I've created a new application, it has 1 activity which has 1 button (scan button) and 2 textviews (which are just going to output the formatname and contents that Zxing returns at the moment).

I have followed the ScanningViaIntent tutorial but it doesn't seem to be hitting `onActivityResult`

Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    Button btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}

public void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i("result", "hit line");
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    if(scanResult != null)
    {
        System.out.println("format: " + scanResult.getFormatName());
        System.out.println("contents: " + scanResult.getContents());



        tv1.setText(scanResult.getFormatName());
        tv2.setText(scanResult.getContents());
    }
    else
    {
        tv1.setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

TextView1 never says "Error" so it doesn't seem that scanResult is null and my Log.i() line is never hit so I'm thinking that `onActivityResult` isn't even being hit.

Could it be to do with making IntentIntegrator `final` for the OnClick() method? When I created IntentIntegrator inside OnClick(), I used getParent() to pass the Activity to the constructor but this force closed my app with a NullReferenceException inside IntentItegrator.

Am I using the library correctly?

Thanks for your time,

Poncho

Comment: Do you have CaptureActivity class?

Comment: Hi, no I just have 1 activity which is the main, does the tutorial mention anything about a CaptureActivity class?

Comment: I have copied the IntentIntegrator and IntentResult classes into my application and I have the Zxing application installed as a separate app (called Barcode Scanner).

Comment: please also post code relating to your `IntentIntegrator` as it seems to make or break this functionallity. Also calling getParent() is wrong: If you don't want to have a final IntentIntegrator inside your `onClick` you could just call `YourActivityName.this`

Comment: FWIW, here is a working sample project that does pretty much everything your code does: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing

Comment: @RafaelT sorry I don't quite get what you mean? It seems I either have to put the IntentIntegrator into the onClick which means I need a reference to the Activity or put the IntentIntegrator outside the onClick which means it must be 'final'.

Comment: @CommonsWare wow that does look exactly the same thanks!

But when does doScan() get called?

Comment: @RafaelT I changed the constructor to IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this) but I'm still getting the same problem, the app is started, it finds a book and then on return to my app OnActivityResult does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually overriding the method `onActivityResult()` because you have implemented `OnActivityResult()`. Your method is not being called as a result. Everything else looks about right.

This is the kind of thing you catch if you use `@Override` annotations -- good habit, since it would have caught this.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `startActivityForResult(..)`? You may want to use something like this :

```
Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

// check which types of codes to scan for
if (desiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
  // set the desired barcode types
  StringBuilder joinedByComma = new StringBuilder();
  for (String format : desiredBarcodeFormats) {
    if (joinedByComma.length() > 0) {
      joinedByComma.append(',');
    }
    joinedByComma.append(format);
  }
  intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", joinedByComma.toString());
}

String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
if (targetAppPackage == null) {
  return showDownloadDialog();
}
intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
attachMoreExtras(intentScan);
startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
```

**findTargetAppPackage** :

```
 private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
    PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (availableApps != null) {
      for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
        String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (targetApplications.contains(packageName)) {
          return packageName;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

To see a more complete example go [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java).

Comment: Thanks but I thought the whole point of IntentIntegrator and IntentResult was so you didn't have to do all this, it is like a wrapper for this stuff right?

Comment: This is not necessary, correct. You should just use IntentIntegrator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the latest classes from the repository
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android

See the javadoc of the class to see how to use it. First add code to invoke the Intent:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Second, add this to your Activity to handle the result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,      intent);
    if (scanResult != null) {
        // handle scan result
    }
    // else continue with any other code you need in the method
}
```

More info here https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent